# How to change data type of a cv::mat in Qt Qdebuger

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator, qdebug

I want see the stored data in my `cv::mat` data using Qdebuger. My problem is that the data-type of my `cv::mat` is `uchar` while the depth of my `mat` is `cv_32f` and I cannot change to a float type.

[image: image of my problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT Creator has a special feature to give ability to visualize complex structures more user-friendly. It's called [Debugging Helpers](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html).

You should write your own debugging helper for `cv::mat` type. Look [qttypes.py](https://github.com/coldpeace/qt-creator-bb/blob/master/qt-creator/share/qtcreator/dumper/qttypes.py) for the samples.